# How can I check curl api key is authorized or not in reciever side

Tags: php, rest, api, curl

Hi all am pushing data from one website to other website using curl it is working great now but i want to add a token or apikey or key in receiver side url. How can i write in receiver side code.whether the token or apikey or key is matched or not .but the apikey or token is not from database .
below is my code

This code is senderside: using curl and parameter apikey

```
    $payload = json_encode(array("users" => $json['users']));
     $post_json = json_encode($content);     
         $apikey = 'OTM2NTQ0MwMTA3MDYxMQNDAxOTU2MwMTA4MDQ1MgMzIzMDAyMA';    
           $endpoint = 'http://localhost/apib/data.php?apikey='.$api_key;
            $ch1 = @curl_init();
            @curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            @curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
            @curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
            @curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
            @curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $response = @curl_exec($ch1);
            $status_code = @curl_getinfo($ch1, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            $curl_errors = curl_error($ch1);
            @curl_close($ch1);
            /*echo "curl Errors: " . $curl_errors;
            echo "\nStatus code: " . $status_code;
            echo "\nResponse: " . $response;*/
            echo "\nResponse: " . $response;
```

In other websites data is below: how can i write code for apikey here

```
   \$jfile = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $final_res = json_decode($jfile, true) ;
    $dataaa =  $final_res['users'];
    $apikey;  
    global $db;
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "apis");
    if($db === false){
      die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
```

Now I want send data through api key..how can i write in receiver side  whether it is correct or not

Comment: You could encrypt your data using an initial value and then attach a HMAC to it.  This, if done properly will insure that your data has not been tampered with form web page A to web page b.  Both Web page A and B share the same key.  I would recommend using the libSodium encryption library. Here is a link that talks about this. https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly

Comment: no no .i just want like apikey in senderside should match in apikey recevier side

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

For Page A, lets add your api key to your json array before you send it. Like this:

```
$myData = array("users" => $json['users']);

$key = 'OTM2NTQ0MwMTA3MDYxMQNDAxOTU2MwMTA4MDQ1MgMzIzMDAyMA';

$api_key = array('apikey' => $key);

$myData = $myData + $api_key;

$payload = json_encode($myData);

$endpoint = 'http://localhost/apib/data.php';

$ch1 = @curl_init();
        @curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        @curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
        @curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
        @curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
        @curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = @curl_exec($ch1);
        $status_code = @curl_getinfo($ch1, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        $curl_errors = curl_error($ch1);
        @curl_close($ch1);
        /*echo "curl Errors: " . $curl_errors;
        echo "\nStatus code: " . $status_code;
        echo "\nResponse: " . $response;*/
        echo "\nResponse: " . $response;
```

If all you want to do is compare the value of the key from page A to page B then you can do something like this for page B.

Page B:

```
    $api_key = 'OTM2NTQ0MwMTA3MDYxMQNDAxOTU2MwMTA4MDQ1MgMzIzMDAyMA';

    $jfile = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $final_res = json_decode($jfile, true);

    print_r($final_res);        

    $dataaa =  $final_res['users'];     


    if($api_key == $final_res['apikey']){        


      echo 'The api key matches.';

      global $db;
      $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "apis");
      if($db === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
      }

    } else { 

      echo 'The api key does not match.';
      exit();

    }
```

This is bad practice because it appears as though your api key will be constant.  Anyone who sees the api key will be able to use it at will to do whatever page B does.  There is not a true safeguard here.  And if your api key is used for anything else that may be important your sharing it to the world.

If you do what I suggested in my comment the api key can be shared between page A and B but the actual value attached to the api key in the post request will change every time it is sent. But you will be able to decrypt it and it will always be the api key.  If not then there was a problem.  Plus you will be able guarantee that that any other data you sent has also not been tampered with provided your secret keys have not been compromised.

I strongly urge you to read this link:

https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly

To do what you are doing it's actually not all that difficult, you just have to familiarize yourself with the library you choose and the methods that are needed.

Comment: the apikey is does not change every time.only single unique api key it was.soo my actuall task is in curl i need to call with apikey as a parameter

Comment: My solution should do what you need for page B.  Test it with your code and let me know.

Comment: am getting apikey doesn't match

Comment: $api_key = 'OTM2NTQ0MwMTA3MDYxMQNDAxOTU2MwMTA4MDQ1MgMzIzMDAyMA';

    if($api_key == $final_res['apikey']){

      echo 'The api key matches.';
global $db;
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "apis");
if($db === false){
  die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
}
else { 

      echo 'The api key does not match.';
      exit();

    }

Comment: See my updated answer, you should put the api key variable into the json array on page A for the "$payload" variable

Comment: hang on.  Im going to put full code up there in my answer.

Comment: notice I changed the url, you don't need it the way you had it.